# WebSocketContainer.connectToServer seems to hang

Tags: java, websocket

When I try to make a websocket session through a Java application using WebSocketContainter.connectToServer everything seems to hang. I don't get any indication there was an exception, or that the connection was successfully made. My code doesn't execute past the connectToServer call.

```
    String DEFAULT_URI = "ws://blah/ws/test";
    WebSocketContainer wsContainer =  ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    Session session = wsContainer.connectToServer(MyClient.class, new URI(DEFAULT_URI));

    //this line never gets executed. Session from above isn't returned nor is an error
    System.out.println(session);
```

From this example, I'd expect some sort of connection error seeing that I'm trying to establish a connection to a websocket address that isn't valid. When using a valid ws address I also don't progress past getting the connection to return a session.

Comment: Did you check whether you can actually make a successful TCP connection from your client machine to the target machine? Sometimes firewalls hang connection requests forever.

Comment: Yes I can access this via TCP. The hanging is due to using Self Signed Certificates, which are being treated as invalid. Is there any way to turn down the validation (or off) so that I can ignore self signed cert errors?

Comment: Which side is showing a self-signed certificate - the server or the client?

Comment: This could be somehow implementation dependent - there might be some timeout which would react on event like that, especially when there is ssl/tls involved. Can you please share which implementation (don't forget the version) you are using?

Comment: Yes I can make the connection via TCP

Comment: <dependency>
<groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId> <version>1.1</version></dependency>